# Magento tax issue, tax is not counted

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

We have a strange issue in one of our shops. We have set all the tax settings, it are the same settings as by all of our shops and by this particular shop in the shopping cart and by orders tax is sometimes not counted. So by some orders we see tax and by others we do not.

So if we look at a product in de admin of the shop we see the tax so know that tax is counted,but when we put it in our cart he will not take tax.

It is also not a country issue, because we have just one country to choose from.

Has any one had the same problem or ideas what can be wrong?

Comment: it doesn't calcualte the tax in the shopping cart? or just doesn't show? are you sure you setted including tax in shopping cart? have you change any cart file recently? can you try a different template to see if there is a problem with your template? too many questions.. haha.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We have found the problem. In the store view the tax was set different then overall, so there to no tax and in the overall normal tax.